# How can I play Vimeo 360 video from url to my app?

Tags: ios, vimeo, xcode10

I am searching out the SDK for playing Vimeo 360 video in my application, but I am not able to find out any way to play the video, even safari is also not supporting the 360 player, is there any framework exist to play Vimeo 360 video in my application in `Objective-C` or `Swift`?

Answer (score 2):

To play 360 video on your own application you need to implement 360 video player or you can use third party sdk  of google cardboard follow the link

https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/ios/get-started

and some codes may help for your own player implementation if you are going to custom player for your own

https://medium.com/@hanton.yang/how-to-create-a-360-video-player-with-opengl-es-3-0-and-glkit-360-3f29a9cfac88

hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

While Vimeo does have an SDK for playing Vimeo videos within iOS apps, 360 video playback is not supported with the library alone. The Vimeo iOS app actually uses the Google VR SDK to handle 360 video playback, which can be found here: https://cocoapods.org/pods/GVRSDK